# CakePHP multiple nested query

Tags: mysql, cakephp-1.3

I want my query as:

```
$conditions = array(
                        'ManageTrackby.trackby_num NOT LIKE' => '%n/a%',
                        'Balancesheet.subscriber_id' => $_SESSION['Auth']['User']['subscriber_id'],
                        'Balancesheet.show_id' => $this->Session->read('openshowid'),
                        'OR' => array('Balancesheet.season_id' => $season_id,  'Balancesheet.season_id is null'),
                        'OR' => array('Balancesheet.episode_id'=> $episode_id, 'Balancesheet.episode_id is null')
                    );
```

which skips last `OR` option here and giving below result:

```
Array
(
[ManageTrackby.trackby_num NOT LIKE] => %n/a%
[Balancesheet.subscriber_id] => 105
[Balancesheet.show_id] => 56
[OR] => Array
    (
        [Balancesheet.episode_id] => 86
        [0] => Balancesheet.episode_id is null
    )
```

)

Here, it misses `SEASON_ID` from the condition, any idea why?

Please guide me !

Comment: Is this what you want your query be? `Balancesheet.season_id = $season_id OR Balancesheet.season_id = Null
       AND
       Balancesheet.episode_id = $episode_id OR Balancesheet.episode_id = Null`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. If you want all the first conditions, plus an or of the second conditions, then you will want the OR within the AND array. For complex finds, look up the info on this page http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html

```
$conditions = array(
   'AND' => array(
                  'ManageTrackby.trackby_num NOT LIKE' => '%n/a%',
                  'Balancesheet.subscriber_id' => $_SESSION['Auth']['User']['subscriber_id'],
                  'Balancesheet.show_id' => $this->Session->read('openshowid')
            )
   'OR' => array(
    array('Balancesheet.season_id' => $season_id,  'Balancesheet.season_id is null'),
            array('Balancesheet.episode_id'=> $episode_id, 'Balancesheet.episode_id is null')
            )
               )
```

Answer (score 0):

Your array is setting the OR element twice. Put the two OR statements in their own individual array:

```
  $conditions = array(
    'ManageTrackby.trackby_num NOT LIKE' => '%n/a%',
    'Balancesheet.subscriber_id' => $_SESSION['Auth']['User']['subscriber_id'],
    'Balancesheet.show_id' => $this->Session->read('openshowid'),
array('OR' => array('Balancesheet.season_id' => $season_id,  'Balancesheet.season_id is null')),
array('OR' => array('Balancesheet.episode_id'=> $episode_id, 'Balancesheet.episode_id is null'))
);
```